# Disable VMWare Workstation VMEM file

Tags: vmware-workstation

I'm using VMWare Workstation 15.1.0 on Windows 10 x64 1903. My VMs are on SSD so I want to disable the .vmem files which appears when the VM is running and disappear when the VM is shut down. I don't think the .vmem file which is the same size as the RAM size of the VM is very useful, and it just waste the TBW of the SSD and possibly slow down the system since the SSD write bandwidth is mostly not stable.

The online search results are all outdated.

Comment: This works for Win10+VW15: edit "C:\ProgramData\VMware\VMware Workstation\settings.ini" as Administrator, and add a line : mainMem.useNamedFile = "FALSE"

Comment: that works great!